# How to use column.nextval with oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have a column in my table for an ID that is normally populated with .nextval. The .nextval works perfectly as a normal sql statement such as `INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COLA, COLB, COLC) VALUES (COLA_SEQ.nextval, 'ABCD', '25-JUL-2019');` Where COLA is a number, COLB is a `varchar`, and `COLC` is a date field. In node I am attempting to insert into the database as follows:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const async = require('async');

// Database connect function
const doconnect = function (cb) {
    oracledb.getConnection(database, cb);
};

// Database disconnect function
const dorelease = function (conn) {
    conn.close(function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.error(err.message);
    });
};

// Database insert function
const doinsert = function (conn, cb) {
    let table = "MYTABLE";
    let inserts = [{
        COLA: 'COLA_SEQ.nextval',
        COLB: 'ABCD',
        COLC: '25-JUL-2019'
    }];

    // Extract object keys from inserts and format them for Oracle
    // Oracle format needed => (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_C)
    let keys = Object.keys(inserts[0]);
    keys = '(' + keys.join(', ') + ')';

    // Extract object keys from inserts as value placeholders and format them for Oracle
    // Oracle format needed => (:COLUMN_A, :COLUMN_A, :COLUMN_C)
    let vals = Object.keys(inserts[0]);
    vals.forEach(function (element, idx) {
        vals[idx] = ':' + element;
    });
    vals = '(' + vals.join(', ') + ')';

    // Build sql insert statement
    // Oracle format needed => "INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_A, COLUMN_C) VALUES (:COLUMN_A, :COLUMN_A, :COLUMN_C)"
    var sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " " + keys + " VALUES " + vals;

    var options = {
        autoCommit: false,
        batchErrors: true
    };

    // Insert all data into Oracle database
    conn.executeMany(sql, inserts, options, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
            return cb(err, conn);
        else {
            // Commit all changes made
            conn.commit();

            return cb(null, conn);
        }
    });
};

// Async waterfall for sequential code exection (connect > query > disconnect)
async.waterfall(
    [
        doconnect,
        doinsert
    ],
    function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("In waterfall error cb: ==>", err, "<==");
            response.status = String(err);
        }
        if (conn)
            dorelease(conn);
    });
```

The error Oracle returns is

> "Error: ORA-01722: invalid number"

which makes sense because .nextval is being passes as a string to a field that is a number. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the statement to oracle without it being read as a string.

Comment: It's a common practice to create a trigger which handles calling `sequence.nextval`. That way you don't have to insert anything for the primary key column - it's still required, but the trigger will handle it. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536350500346853724

Comment: I'd much rather use triggers for this, but I got push back from the DBA managing my server.

Comment: For future reference, Oracle DB 12.1 introduced identity columns to remove the need for sequences and triggers in cases like this.  For example, `CREATE TABLE itinerary (id NUMBER(11) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will produce a query:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C) VALUES (:COLUMN_A, :COLUMN_B, :COLUMN_C)
```

and then will try to assign the value `'COLA_SEQ.nextval'` to the first bind variable. This value is a String it is not a Number (which is the data type expected for the column) and it is not a request to use a sequence.

If you want to use a sequence then you need to generate a query that is:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C) VALUES ( COLA_SEQ.nextval, :COLUMN_B, :COLUMN_C)
```

That does not use a bind variable but has the sequence in the statement.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I have tried this prior. Oracle returns "Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number". Have you ever encountered this when using your method?

Comment: @user32521 Were you still trying to pass 3 bind variables into the stored procedure even though there are now only two?

Comment: I forgot to delete COLA for each object. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: In the response, I am getting { lastRowid: 'AAADaFAAEAAAAD3AAI', rowsAffected: 1 } however, the sequence is integer. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: @AhmedNumaan There is insufficient context in your comment to be able to answer as your query does not appear to be related to this answer as an `INSERT` statement does not produce a response like that. I suggest that you ask a new question and include a [MRE] with full details of your tables, sample data, your query, the actual response/error/issue and your expected output.